# Rescaling one-dimensional map to normal form

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, change-of-variable, bifurcation

(This is part of exercise 10.7.8 in Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos that I am struggling to solve)

QUESTION:

Consider the map $x_{n+1} = f(x_n,r)$ where $f(x_n,r)=-r+x-x^2$. We use the notation $f^2(x,r)=f(f(x,r))$. Plot $f(x,r)$ and $f^2(x,r)$ and observe that they look like scaled versions of each other for $x$ small and $r$ small. Let us show this more concretely.

Expand $f^2(x,r)$ around $x=0$ keeping terms through $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$. Now rescale $x$ and $r$ to put this new map into the normal form $F(X,R) \approx -R + X + X^2$.

MY ATTEMPTS:

Taking the Taylor expansion of
$f^2(x,r)$, we get

$f^2(x,r) = -r(r+2) + (2r+1)x -2(r+1)x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$.

Let's cut off the higher-order terms and equal it to the normal form

$
T(x,r) := -r(r+2) + (2r+1)x -2(r+1)x^2 = -R + X - X^2.
$

Now, as we are asked to scale $x$ and $r$, we assume $X = \alpha x$ and $R=\beta r$. But from here, I am not able to find $\alpha$ or $\beta$. I thought maybe I could ignore second-order terms of $r$ but this is also a dead-end.

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Comment: Edited the question to include what I've done so far.

Comment: You are, quite implicitly, asked to find an equivalency of $x_{2n+2}=f^2(x_{2n},r)$ and $X_{n+1}=F(X_n,R)$. This influences what terms you have to compare if $X_n=αx_{2n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate on why this would influence which terms are being compared? As far as I understand, we are asked to verify that the $f^2(x,r)$ map is approximated by $F(X,R)$. Its role as the second iterate of the map does not matter, I would think?

Comment: That you would have to check in the source, I think from context it would make more sense to construct an approximately equivalent dynamical system. Also check if "rescale" is really only a propotional-linear function, or if affine-linear functions are also admissible.

Comment: Yes, okay. I realize I should add more context. By plotting $f(x,r)$ and $f^2(x,r)$, we can see that for $x$ and $r$ small, they look like scaled versions of each other. Therefore, I am quite confident that proportional-linear scale is sufficient. Let me edit the question so this is clear.